# The concept of countries/a country/ the country/ country

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct "the concept of countries", "the concept of a country", "the concept of the country" or "the concept of country"?

I thought that "the concept of country" is correct because "country" is used here as a conceptual idea and not countable.
But, today I realized it seems to be wrong thanks to Google.

Would you please give me some explanation on this question?

.

FIRST EDIT:

Thank you for your replies.
I understand I should have given some contexts.

"What is the concept of a country" - "A country is not a set of persons."

"What is the concept of countries" - "A country is not a set of persons."

"In this world, even cats form a country" - "What is the concept of the country?"

"What is the concept of country" - "A country is not a set of persons."

Are the sentences above correct?

Comment: It really depends on which or what you're trying to say. I can think of examples where each would be correct.

Comment: This is the kind of question that is unlikely to generate useful responses without some additional context, such as the surrounding text and/or the situation in which the expression is (or will be / might be) used.

Comment: This question may be better on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that "the concept of country" is correct because "country" is used here as a conceptual idea and not countable.

That is a valid use, and the one I would recommend.

The others can all be used for the same case:

> The concept of the country.

Here we imagine a hypothetical platonic *country* to discuss the concept, and since there is only one such country, we use the definite article.

> The concept of countries.

Here we consider the plurality of countries that exist, and consider them all.

> The concept of a country.

Here we consider one example of the plurality mentioned above, as an example of the concept.

So we could use all of these for the purpose you have.

However, we can use each of these in more specific ways too.

> The concept of the country.

Can be used to refer to *the country* as in the countryside, differentiated from the urban environment, and the various ways this bucolic concept has been dealt with, such as the pastoral style in art.

> The concept of countries.

Here we could be focusing on the interactions between nation states.

> The concept of a country.

Here we could be focusing on the ways the populace generally and statesmen in particular argue their country "stands for" particular values.

I'm not aiming to be exhaustive, and I'm sure we could find other cases where each of these serve particularly well. Since your use of "the concept of country" does not fit any of these, it makes it clearer as to just what it does mean.

Some styles would also italicise *country*, which I'd recommend myself, though it's by no means the only valid style:

> The concept of *country*.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of a country or the concept of countries is correct. The concept of the country implies there is only one country and you are getting the concept of it. The concept of country implies that a country is not a physical object.

Comment: I think you are incorrect here. There is a difference between the concept of "nation" and the *concept of "country"*. Country can be thought of in concept, as can be a great many other things (e.g. *the concept of money*).